# Is there a metric that is zero for translations?

Tags: metric-spaces, recreational-mathematics

First define a relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Z}^k$ such that for any $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}^k$ where $a=(a_1,\dotsc,a_k)$, and $b=(b_1,\dotsc,b_k)$ we write $a\sim b$ if and only if $a-b=(n,n,\dotsc,n)$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. It is easily verified that this is an equivalence relation and partitions the $k$-tuples of integers into translation classes, i.e. $$a=(a_1,\dotsc,a_k), a+1=(a_1+1,\dotsc,a_k+1),\dotsc,$$ $$a+n=(a_1+n,\dotsc,a_k+n),\dotsc$$
 represents the same class, denoted $[a]$. 
Is it possible to define a metric on $\mathbb{Z}^k$ such that for fixed $k$-tuples of integers $a=(a_1,\dotsc,a_k)$, we have

1)
$$d(a,a+n)=d(a,a)=0$$ for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$? Additionally is it possible to define it so that

2) 
 $$d(a,b)=0$$ if and only if $a\sim b$.

Rephrased: The distance between two $k$-tuples of integers is zero if and only if they are in the same translation class.

Examples:
$$(0,4,7) \text{ and } (1,5,8)$$
should have distance zero, while
$$(0,4,7) \text{ and } (1,5,9)$$ should have non-zero distance.

Context: i am a musician trying to have some fun w math as follows: i want to define a metric on $k$-tuples of integers in a way to represent the pitches of a melody and the distances between two melodies. I want melodies that are mere transpositions of each other to have "distance" zero while two melodies that cannot be obtained from one another via transposition to have non zero distance.

In my work in the $k$-tuples i had defined for any $k$-note melodies $a,b$ with pitch representation $a=(p_1,\dotsc,p_k)$ and  $b=(q_1,\dotsc,q_k)$ the "metric" (i must prove it is a metric yet!)
$d(a,b)=|\Delta p_i - \Delta q_i|$
Where $\Delta p_i=|p_i-p_{i+1}|$. This satisfies the property 1) i.e. that $d(a,a+n)=0$
(Using the def: $a+n=(p_1+n,\dotsc,p_k+n)$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$) but i am stuck showing it would satisfy property 2). Is property 2) false for my candidate metric? Is it even possible to find a metric where both 1) and 2) to hold?

(Sorry for the multiple edits, I asked a little too hastily before thinking everything through)

Comment: The ddistance axioms stipulate that $d(a,b)=0$ if and only if $a=b$.

Comment: @Bernard What if i form an equivalence relation by which elements are transpositions of each other? Then $a+n$ and $a$ represent the same point and wouldn't violate that axiom of distance.

Comment: That's another problem. But we must see the context.

Comment: Based on your edits, you might consider equivalence classes where the absolute pitch of the first note is ignored, i.e. the remainder are relative to the first. So $\hat{d}( (p_1,p_2,...,p_n), (q_1,q_2,...,q_n)) = d( (p_2-p_1,...,p_n-p_1), (q_2-q_1,...,q_n-q_1))$

Comment: I have revised the question and added some examples. I will take in Webb's suggestion, user254665's answer, and Schweber's comment to that answer into consideration later today when I am working on this. Sorry for the many edits everyone and thank you!

Comment: @A.Webb After working with this suggestion I'd like to thank you a lot! With this it seems I can work out $\hat{d}(a,b)=0$ if and only if $a\sim b$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a metric on any set. If you want a metric on the equivalence classes of $R$, where $x\equiv y \iff x-y\in Z,$ that has some relation to the algebraic structure of $R,$ I suggest $$d(x_E,y_E)=|(x-[x])-(y-[y])|$$ where $[x]$ is the largest integer not exceeding $x,$ and $x_E$ is the equivalence class containing $x$. Observe that for each $x\in R$ there is a unique $x'\in [0,1)\cap x_E$, so $d(x_E,y_E)=|x'-y'|.$

Comment: Note that another way to phrase this metric which might make it look more natural is: the distance between two tuples is the minimal distance between their representatives. That is, $d(x_E, y_E)$ is the minimum of $d(a, b)$ for $a\sim x, b\sim y$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very insightful but I don't want a metric on the equivalence classes of $\mathbb{R}$. I want a metric on the equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ (formed from the relation i defined in the beginning of the question). Am I missing the connection here? Perhaps the more general question I am asking is: given a set $X$ with a metric and an equivalence relation defined, is it possible to define a new metric that distinguishes between the equivalence classes? It seems this is what you're answering, at least in the case of $R$, if I am thinking correctly.